# Converting epoch timestamp into 15 minute intervals for Impala

Tags: hadoop, epoch

Guys I need help writing a script with a hadoop based db.I need to know about a unixtime or related formula that would convert the timestamp into readable 15 minute intervals.Currently I am using below formula to convert the timestamp into complete readable time.

```
from_unixtime(starttime+3*3600,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
```

and it gives me output like:

```
date_t
2016/03/10 01:24
2016/03/10 12:22
2016/03/10 04:48
2016/03/10 04:25
2016/03/10 14:19
```

But I need it this way:

```
date_t
2016/03/10 01:00
2016/03/10 01:15
2016/03/10 01:30
2016/03/10 01:45
```

I have tried to multiply it by 900 instead of 3600 but no change in result.
Seems like some very small thing that I am missing but would appreciate if I get help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
 from_unixtime(3*3600+900*ceil(starttime/900),"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
```

I supposed

- `ceil` truncate to int (it is a mysql function)
- `startime` is a number of second
- you add a 3 hour offset.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround like this:

```
from_unixtime((starttime+3*3600)-(starttime+3*3600)%900,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
```